# Having "PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so", "… pam_kwallet5.so", "… pam_kwallet.so" on start of smbd, ssh, cron daemons - why and how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, samba, cron, pam

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.
I tried to read my log files for errors.
The most interesting are the following:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log | egrep "unable|faulty"

Nov 25 13:25:13 localhost su[4491]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 25 13:25:13 localhost su[4491]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 25 13:25:13 localhost systemd: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 25 13:25:13 localhost systemd: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 25 13:29:21 localhost smbd: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 25 13:29:21 localhost smbd: PAM adding faulty module: pam_winbind.so
Nov 25 13:39:01 localhost CRON[5247]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
Nov 26 23:53:53 localhost lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Nov 26 23:53:53 localhost lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 26 23:53:53 localhost lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Nov 26 23:53:53 localhost lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_winbind.so): /lib/security/pam_winbind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
```

The system integrity is correct - `debsums --config --changed` does not report any changes in `/etc/pam.d` directory.

The library files are not installed:

```
$ dpkg -S pam_winbind.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *pam_winbind.so*

$ dpkg -S pam_kwallet.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *pam_kwallet.so*

$ dpkg -S pam_kwallet5.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *pam_kwallet5.so*
```

Why are these messages exist in `/var/log/auth.log`?
Should I fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings may be removed by installation of the corresponding packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5 libpam-winbind
```

But I got the interesting result - my user is listed only [in its group](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097893/66509).

Fixed this problem by removing both kwallet packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5
```

The mentioned KWallet problem is known on LaunchPad as [bug 1781418](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwallet-pam/+bug/1781418).

---

So it was a bad idea to remove these warnings. I'll remove PAM winbind too for sure:

```
sudo apt-get purge libpam-winbind
```

Comment: So, is this solution suggesting to install, and then purge the same packages? Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know your exact situation. My vision and walk-through is in above answer. Removing packages helped me.

Comment: OK, though your solution first installs some packages, and then removes those same packages. In my case, installing them helped to remove those errors but it would hang later on. I switched desktop manager (from `lightdm` to `gdm3`) and the error disappeared. Maybe `gdm3` does not use them.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention I got a similar error related to a different package flooding my journald

```
$ journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
Dec 13 21:35:31 uminefi01 sudo[168527]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed >
Dec 13 21:35:40 uminefi01 sudo[168564]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_zfs_key.so): />
Dec 13 21:35:40 uminefi01 sudo[168564]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_zfs_key.so
Dec 13 21:35:40 uminefi01 sudo[168564]:    avery : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/avery/>
Dec 13 21:35:40 uminefi01 sudo[168564]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened >
Dec 13 21:35:40 uminefi01 sudo[168564]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed >
Dec 13 21:35:51 uminefi01 sudo[168599]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_zfs_key.so): />
Dec 13 21:35:51 uminefi01 sudo[168599]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_zfs_key.so
```

... and so on ...

Found it with `apt-file`, apparently it just wasn't installed

```
$ sudo dpkg -S pam_zfs_key.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *pam_zfs_key.so*

$ apt-file search pam_zfs_key.so
libpam-zfs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_zfs_key.so

$ sudo apt install -y libpam-zfs
```

Now I can actually use journald to debug real problems again