# Terminal shows that my user is only a member of its group, but it is not true - how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, ssh, user-management, groups

I went to strange situation on my laptop (running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS).

All terminals show that my `sudo`-able user is only a member of its group:

```
$ whoami 
norbert
$ groups 
norbert
$ id
uid=1000(norbert) gid=1000(norbert) groups=1000(norbert)

$ grep norbert /etc/passwd
norbert:x:1000:1000:Norbert,,,:/home/norbert:/bin/bash
```

but it is not true as my user is listed in `/etc/groups`:

```
$ grep norbert /etc/group
adm:x:4:norbert,syslog
disk:x:6:norbert
lp:x:7:norbert
dialout:x:20:norbert
cdrom:x:24:norbert
www-data:x:33:norbert
plugdev:x:46:norbert
fuse:x:104:norbert,tester
lpadmin:x:105:norbert
admin:x:119:norbert
norbert:x:1000:
sambashare:x:122:norbert
vboxusers:x:124:norbert
debian-tor:x:129:norbert,tester
local:x:1001:norbert
libvirtd:x:138:norbert
wireshark:x:126:norbert
```

As the result I can't use Arduino IDE and Wireshark.

If I login to this system from SSH - I can see all groups:

```
$ groups
norbert adm disk lp dialout cdrom www-data plugdev fuse lpadmin admin sambashare vboxusers wireshark debian-tor libvirtd local
```

Why this happened? What should I do to debug and fix this behavior?

Comment: Did you do the obvious thing and reboot (or maybe at least log out completely) already?

Comment: @ByteCommander Thank you! But it was a bug, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was linked with my other question about [PAM warnings in `/var/log/auth.log`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097915/66509).

The problem was caused by manually installed PAM KWallet modules. I have installed both (`libpam-kwallet4` and `libpam-kwallet5`), but they can't be installed in the same time as described in the [bug 1781418 on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwallet-pam/+bug/1781418).

I fixed my problem by removing two PAM modules:

```
sudo apt-get purge libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5
```

and then rebooted.