# why does my user not belong to other groups until password is entered?

Tags: permissions, password, users, groups

I have the problem that when I open a graphical shell in `KDE` (`XTerm` or `Konsole`, both show the same "problem") and I type `groups`, the only group displayed carries my user's name. I need to first do `su user` & enter the password before all the user becomes a member of the other groups. On any of tthe consoles, the group membership is correct directly after login.

I have been able to verify (with my `docker` membership) that it is not only a display option but it actually directly affects group membership, i.e. the user does not act as a member of group `docker` until I actually re-authenticate as "myself". Why is this, that doesn't seem right?
In `XTerm` it might look something like:

```
user@regDesktopHome:~$ groups
user
user@regDesktopHome:~$ su user
Password: 
user@regDesktopHome:~$ groups
user sudo dip netdev vboxusers wireshark docker
user@regDesktopHome:~$
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Terminal shows that my user is only a member of its group, but it is not true - how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097893/terminal-shows-that-my-user-is-only-a-member-of-its-group-but-it-is-not-true)